# Do a comparison between the different types of symmetric protocols used by SSH?

Tags: networking, ssh, encryption

I want to use the SSH protocol to transmit a file but each time with a different cryptography method (3DES, Blowfish ..) to make a comparison between them in terms of time and throughput.

First question: How can I configure the encryption protocol used?

Second question: Is there a tool to extract information about the protocols used (latency, throughput, time for encryption, decryption time)?

Comment: You might be able to extract some ideas from [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2271473). I used `top` to try to monitor what was going on during large file transfers. i didn't care about weak encryption, because it was all on my LAN.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I configure the encryption protocol used?

You can use `-c <cipher_of_choice>` option, or `-o Cipher=<cipher_of_choice>`. The default cipher is `3des`, and of course, refrain from using any weak or broken cipher.

> Is there a tool to extract information about the protocols used (latency, troughput, time for encryption, decryption time)?

With `ssh`, you can play with `-v` (`--verbose`) option, use `-vvv` to get maximum verbosity.

Also look at `LogLevel` directive for `ssh_config` and `sshd_config`. Use `LogLevel DEBUG3` (maximum verbosity) and look at `/var/log/auth.log` (beware of any potential flooding of messages). I am not sure whether you would get the desired stuffs from these, but this is the best `ssh` alone can provide you with.